# User local images while development of angular application

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-material

i'm currently developing an angular frontend application, running it locally in the ide without a webserver to provide some images. For running the app i use `ng serve`.

I have no idea on how to use images. played along with some path stuff .. but without success.

The images are stored in app/img

thx.

Comment: please provide information about what have you tried and what is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the images in the `src/assets` folder.

If you have an image named `example.png`. The URL would be:

```
/assets/example.png
```

If you want a different location. You can add additional assets locations by modifying the `angular.json` file.

To add an `app/img` folder:

```
 "assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "src/assets",
    "src/app/img"
 ]
```